# Como adicionar CR ou LF ao fim do arquivo .pdf gerado pelo Stella.Boleto?

Tags: java, java-ee, pdf, boleto, caelum-stella

Gerei um boleto do itau e fui indicado a validar junto a operadora (banco itau).
A operadora exigiu inserir os caracteres especiais:
 CR+LF.

Como faço isso ?

Answer (score 1):

São os caracteres de Carriage Return e Line Feed. Um é o código ASCII 10 e o outro ASCII 13, não lembro agora qual é qual (também não lembro se é em hexadecimal também, heheh).

Como o charset UTF-8 comporta a tabela ASCII, você pode abrir o arquivo para edição nesse padrão de codificação e acrescentar os caracteres que faltam.

Acredito que seja um par de caracteres ao final de cada linha do boleto.